# How do I convert a SQL query function into a django queryset

Tags: sql, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following sample query from a `.sql` file  how,do I convert it into a django `queryset`:

This is what I have so far :

```
class AdjustmentView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Adjustment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AdjustmentSerializer

    def get_adjustment(self):
        Adjustment.objects.filter(employee_month_id=1,adjustment_type=2)
        .values('exchange_rate','amount').aggregate(Sum('amount', field="exchange_rate*amount") )
```

Just a sample query set will do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAdjustment(int, int, int) RETURNS float AS $$
DECLARE
    adjustment float;
BEGIN

    IF ($3 = 1) THEN
        SELECT SUM(exchange_rate * amount) INTO adjustment
        FROM Employee_Adjustments
        WHERE (Employee_Month_ID = $1) AND (adjustment_type = $2);
    ELSIF ($3 = 2) THEN
        SELECT SUM(exchange_rate * amount) INTO adjustment
        FROM Employee_Adjustments
        WHERE (Employee_Month_ID = $1) AND (adjustment_type = $2) AND (In_payroll = true) AND (Visible = true);
    ELSIF ($3 = 3) THEN
        SELECT SUM(exchange_rate * amount) INTO adjustment
        FROM Employee_Adjustments
        WHERE (Employee_Month_ID = $1) AND (adjustment_type = $2) AND (In_Tax = true);
```

...........................

;

Comment: Did you tried something  ?

Comment: yeah  @Deadpool I have  check its up there.

Comment: Please post what you did up to now.

Comment: I don't think is possible